# MVC - Construct javascript object in my index that will be available in my script file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to initialize in my index javascript object with urls as properties, I need to initialize it on my view because of the @Url.Action that available in my view. so it will look like this:

**Index.cshtml:**

> window.onload = function () {
>
> ```
> myUrls=new Object();
> myUrls.url1='@Url.Action("MyAction1","MyControllerName")';
> myUrls.url2='@Url.Action("MyAction2","MyControllerName")';
> myUrls.url3='@Url.Action("MyAction3","MyControllerName")';
> myUrls.url4='@Url.Action("MyAction4","MyControllerName")';
> }
> ```

Now I have script in my Script folder and I want to access these urls in my script.
How can I achieve this? Can I initialize this object somehow in my script instead of my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've done this inside a function, the `myUrls` variable is scoped to that function. Once the function ends, `myUrls` goes out of scope and is no longer available. To make it stay around, you have to make it global by either taking it out of the `window.onload` (which doesn't make any sense anyways for a static variable declaration), or simply declare the variable first in the global namespace.

```
<script>
    var myUrls;
    window.onload = function () { ... }
</script>
```

But again, like I said, you don't need the `window.onload` because you don't have to wait for the DOM to be ready to declare a variable. So just do:

```
<script>
    var myUrls = {
        url1: ...,
        url2: ...,
        ...
    }
</script>
```

You don't need to create a new object explicitly, just use the object notation `{ ... }`.

Finally, since you're adding this to the global namespace, I *seriously* recommend that you create your own namespace:

```
<script>
    var MyAwesomeAndUniqueNamespace = MyAwesomeAndUniqueNamespace || {};
    MyAwesomeAndUniqueNamespace.myUrls = {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so if I define it just in a script in my view ( not in function ) it will be available in my other scripts that I include in this page?

Comment: also I want to ask if I make my own namespace how I access it from my scripts?

Comment: As long as it's in the global namespace it will be available to any JavaScript that comes *after* it. If you had some external javascript that loads before this script block on the page, then it would *not* have access, because it hasn't been defined yet. Your own namespace is no different, it's global, so it's available just like any other global variable to any script that runs after it's defined.

Comment: I have one more question I see it is work but in my script visual studio not showing me intellisense about "MyAwesomeAndUniqueNamespace" but I checked and it is available in this scope do you know a way that I can see it in intellisence?